# Online applet gives a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

I managed a few times in my past to run an applet online but this one just refuses to run.

Those are my applet files:

### Identifier.jnlp

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase = "http://www.encrymail.co.nf/"  href="Identifier.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Unique-Identifier</title>
        <vendor>Atlantis Atlantis</vendor>
        <icon href="getMac.jpg"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
<security>
      <all-permissions/>
  </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+" href=
           "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="Unique-Identifier.jar"
       //I tried both main = true and main=false.
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <applet-desc
         name="Unique-Identifier"
         main-class="Mac.class"
         width="1"
         height="1">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

### Script in the webpage

```html
<script src=
  "https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>

    var attributes = { id:'Mac',
        code:'Unique-Identifier',  width:1, height:1} ;
    var parameters = { jnlp_href: 'Identifier.jnlp'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
var mac = Mac.Mac2();
```

The manifest file includes:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: http://www.encrymail.co.nf/
Application-Name: Unique-Identifier
```

jar name: Unique-Identifier.jar

class name (the class does not include main method):Mac.class

method that I want to invoke: Mac2(). (returns string).

All the files are in the same folder.

The error I get is `ClassNotFoundException: Mac`.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the Jar to check the class name & location.  Result:

```
main-class="Mac.class"
```

Should be:

```
main-class="mac.class"
```

But note the `.class` part is tolerated rather than correct, so change it to:

```
main-class="mac"
```

Comment: The main class is named Mac and not mac. I've tried it anyway and it gives me the same error: `ClassNotFoundException: mac`

Comment: *"The main class is named Mac and not mac."*  Not in the Jar.  If you don't believe me, download the Jar as it appears on the site, rename it to `.zip`, open it and take a look.  (There are other ways to list the content, that way is just easier.)